# Broadcast Receiver that isn't tied to Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I'm trying to implement an app that times how long my phone screen is on throughout the day using a broadcast receiver.

I'm declaring `Action_Screen_Off/Action_Screen_On` in my broadcast receiver since I can't declare it in my manifest, and I've been debating on the best way to handle storing the amount of time that my screen was on.

Since I can't declare it in the manifest, Should I declare the broadcast receiver inside of the onCreate in my activity? My worry with that is, if my understanding is correct, is that my receiver would then be tied to the lifecycle of the activity and I would only be able to store the on/off times whenever the activity is active.

The whole point of the app is that it's working in the background, and then displaying graphs of usage once an activity is in the foreground.

This led me to think that a Service might be the best bet the handle the Broadcast receiver, but Google seems to now be recommending that we don't use background services, only bounded and foreground services.

How can I make sure that my app is receiving the on/off intents, without the activity that declares the receiver being in the foreground, and the receiver not depending on the lifecycle of that activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a background `Service` for this functionality. Your `Service` doesn't need to actually do anything, but it needs to be active all the time so that you have something to anchor your `BroadcastReceiver` to. In `onCreate()` of your `Service`, create an instance of the `BroadcastReceiver` and register for the screen on/off events. Make sure that you return `START_STICKY` from  your `onStartCommand()` in your `Service`. This will ensure that the `Service` is always active, and Android will restart the `Service` if it kills off your process (for whatever reason). The `BroadcastReceiver` can just write the timestamps of the on/off events to a file, SQLite database or `SharedPreferences` and your `Activity` can then read this data and show the graphs or whatever.

Comment: I don't know why I was under the impression that the Service would usually be doing any writing to a local store, and not the `BroadcastReceiver`. I was going with anchoring the `Service` to the `BroadcastReceiver` for this reason

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Do you need more help?

Comment: please. so my biggest concern with this way of doing it is that if I kill the app, then it no longer detects the screen being on or off. 

If the user starts the app, and the app is in the background it'll work, but as soon as they clear it from the active apps, it stops working.

Comment: What phone are you testing this on?

Comment: Moto g 5 plus running marshmallow

Comment: In general, swiping the app from the list of recent tasks will not prevent your `Service` from being restarted if your `Service` returns `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`. Depending on the version of Android, and any manufacturer's modifications, swiping the app from the list of recent tasks will either kill (and then restart) your `Service` or it will not affect your `Service` at all. There are some devices (notably Xiaomi, Huawei, Lenovo, etc.) where you need to manually add your app to a list of "apps allowed to run in the background" for this to work properly.